# Poor resolution of axes and ticks in `DensityPlot`

Tags: plotting

When I am plotting some data with `Spectrogram` the ticks and axes are very clean and nice, but `DensityPlot` produces a horrible resolution of ticks and axes, why is that?

I am using MMA12.2 on Win64

Here are the results for `Spectrogram`

```
Spectrogram[Table[Cos[i^2] + Sin[i^2], {i, 300}], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

and this is form `DensityPlot`

```
DensityPlot[x y, {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

For both, I save the plots with a right click and save them as png

Comment: I don't know why that is, but I would use `Export` to produce high-quality images for external use and specify a higher resolution using the `ImageResolution` option.